# Calling external method actually calls other method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, methods, extern

I must be asleep already or something because I'm seeing weird things.

I've got a class, called ListSorter (.h/.m), which has 2 extern methods.

The .h looks like:

```
@interface ListSorter : NSObject {

    BOOL eersteKeer;
    Menu_Versie_DrieAppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
-(void)convertList;
-(void)addItemToAlertList:item;
-(void)addItemToHistoryList:item;
```

In an other class, I've imported ListSorter.h in the .h-file, and made an instance of it:

```
#import "ListSorter.h"

@class ListSorter;
@interface CloseIncController : UIViewController {            
    ListSorter *sorter;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ListSorter *sorter;
```

So, in the .m-file, I've got:

```
@synthesize sorter;
...
//Somewhere down in an IB-action
[sorter addItemToHistoryList:keuze];
```

I NSLogged both `addItemToAlertList` and `addItemToHistoryList`, but it always calls `addItemToAlertList`. Why's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it temporarily by creating two classes, both with one of the methods. My guess is the class didn't get allocated properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can add multiple action to a button, check if you don't add addItemToAlertList and addItemToHistoryList to the same button

Comment: I'm afraid it's not linked to a button at all. It just gets called from another class, using `[sorter addItemToHistoryList]`. Then it just links to `addItemToAlertsList` instead of the history list...